# Fixing non-functional ArcMap which was OK day ago?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, windows-7

[image]For about 1 month ArcMap 10.6 was working no issue, in conjunction with Intro to GIS online course. For the past 24 hrs.—approaching final project deadline—data files display, but with Nonsense Attribute Tables, No Data Manipulation function, etc.

I eventually noticed that despite saving all GIS data to file output:
C:\GIS\IntroductionToArcMap_Data\data,  ArcGIS was duplicating and filling with also unknown files at a default geodatabase path: 
C:\Users\Owner\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb

I tried changing path default (1: deleting all GIS files 2: setting Current and Scratch Workspace to outputs via Geoprocessing Environment Settings to paths instructed with initial download data instructions  3: Downloaded initial data (containing source, scratch & results .gdb files)into those paths.)
ArcMap worked for again for about 20min. Still sending out data to same default path—no save or export—just opening data in ArcMap from course download.

I am writing this before I attempt to delete & reinstall ArcMap & all GIS data, but with little optimism that it resolves the issue.

Can anyone offer actual insight into cause(s)/solution(s)?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Have you tried ESRI support?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Unfortunately, in cases where you are not able to provide a detailed list of steps for how someone else will be able to reproduce on their own machine what you are seeing on yours, the expedient to resolving can often be uninstalling/reinstalling.

Comment: Tech Support isn't generally an option for training installs. There's nothing obviously wrong with the details you have provided, and it's not going to be possible for us to reproduce "Nonsense attribute tables". Rather than being your last resort, reinstalling the software should be your first.

Comment: Thanks, for the input. If it does happen to be of use I added a screenshot of my pc info to original. -Ben